# implementation of simple database search in R

Tags: r

I have big data set like as flowing and I want to do simple search on this :

```
>mydata

    ID              TF

    hsa-let-7a-1    SRF
    hsa-let-7a-1    PPARG
    hsa-let-7a-2    AREB6
    hsa-let-7a-3    1-Oct
    hsa-let-7a-3    SRF
    hsa-let-7a-3    PPARG
    hsa-let-7b      SRF
    .               .
    .               .
    .               .
```

**Question**: For a given `y<- c("hsa-let-7a-3","hsa-let-7a-1","hsa-let-7b"...)`, find  elements of `y` which have same TF in `mydata`. some elements of `y` might not be in `ID`, so the checking should be for those elements of y which are in `ID`!.

Finally print them like cluster or group, where in each group/cluster IDs have identical `TF`.
the problem is that, in mydata there are identical  IDs with different `TF`. 
can anybody help me to implement this in R.? 
the output I expect from about example is(all ID in output are in `y`, but not all elements of `y` are in `ID` !) :

```
            ID                TF

>group1       hsa-let-7a-1      SRF
              hsa-let-7a-3      SRF
              hsa-let-7b        SRF

>group2       hsa-let-7a-1      PPARG
              hsa-let-7a-3      PPARG
```

Comment: Is the criterion for showing up in the output that at least two ids from `y` have the same `TF`? Can an element from `y` show up twice or more in the output, for different values of `TF`? Also, can we deduce from your expected output that `hsa-let-7b` is an element of `y`?

Comment: How can you make an example that has `...` in it???

Comment: flodel, I edited the post. answers to your questions: 1) yes 2) yes, can show up more than once as above 3)yes, all elements in outputs are elements of y.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
out <- subset(mydata, ID %in% y)
out <- split(out, out$TF)
out <- out[sapply(out, nrow) > 1]
```

It will return a list of data.frames, one per `TF` with two matches or more.

Comment: @ flodel , I found out, whenever some elements of y are not in ID, this implementation fail to find anything, whoever there still there is same TF in mydata for other elements in y . how can I modify the code to overcome this problem ?

Comment: please provide an example that exhibits this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `data.table` library

```
library(data.table)
mydata<-data.table(mydata)
#order by TF
setkey(mydata,TF)
# Subset data where ID is in y, by group, where each group has more than 1 rows:
z<-mydata[ID %in% y,]
s<-z[,.N>1,by = TF]
#The output of s will be like:
      TF    V1
1: 1-Oct FALSE
2: PPARG  TRUE
3:   SRF  TRUE
# Get output by group
z[TF %in% s[V1==T]$TF]
```

Comment: thanks @Asayat , but I have one problem. the list 'y' comes from other experiment and some elements of y are not in 'ID'. so your implementation found nothing whenever at least one elements of y are not in "ID'. How can I modify 's<-mydata[ID %in% y,.N>1,by = TF]
' such that, do the intended operation for those elements of 'y' which exist in 'ID' ?

Comment: Could you bring an example? Works fine for me, even after I added extra values in y